# how do i turn a array of integers into a vector?

Tags: java

I'm trying to turn an array of inputed integers to a vector, then output the result. I've searched google and every example uses the " (Arrays.asList(randomArray)". However, when i try to compile i get a "cannot find symbol - constructor Vector(java.util.list)"  what is the correct code to convert an array to a vector?

here is my code:

```
Scanner inputNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How big would you like the vector to be?");
int vecSize = inputNumber.nextInt();
int [] vecArray = new int[vecSize];
int [] primeArray = new int[vecSize];
System.out.println("Please enter " + vecSize + " postive numbers please: ");

for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)  {
    int arrayInput = inputNumber.nextInt();
    if (arrayInput > 0){
    vecArray[i] = arrayInput;
    }
}
Vector<Integer> arrayToVec = new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(vecArray));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Vector? If you want synchronization, use `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: ... and if you don't need thread safe synchronization, you can use `ArrayList` or just `Arrays.asList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an array of primitive type (int), which doesnt work well with `Arrays.asList()`. `Arrays.asList(vecArray)` actually returns a `List<int[]>` with one element (your array).

The easiest fix is to populate the vector yourself manually:

```
Vector<Integer> arrayToVec = new Vector<Integer>();
for (int i : vecArray) {
    arrayToVec.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is, that your array is not an `Integer[]` but an `int[]`, and java can't convert between those two types.

You can either replace the `int` by `Integer` or copy the values from the `int[]` to a fresh `Integer[]` (with another loop) and feed that into the vector.

In your code, the last statement tries to copy all `int[]` objects into the vector but you hoped, that  it would automatically inbox and copy the values from the array. But that is not the case.

BTW, the error message gives a hint:

> The constructor `Vector<Integer>(List<int[]>)` is undefined

You expected to use the constructor `Vector<Integer>(List<Integer>)` instead and Java decided to look for the one from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vecArray` should be of type `Integer` instead of primitive `int`.

```
Integer [] vecArray = new Integer[vecSize];
```